# Can juvenile adjudications for never-sealable offences be sealed? (Massachusetts)

Tags: criminal-law, criminal-record

Convictions for some crimes in Massachusetts such as perjury can never be sealed. However, the statute (c.276 § 100A), says that "convictions" for these crimes can never be sealed. So, if a juvenile is adjudicated as a delinquent or as a youthful offender for perjury, can that adjudication be sealed after the relevant waiting period?

Comment: The *However* doesn't make sense in grammar there. Would you mind clearing up what you mean?

Comment: I assume the idea is that a juvenile adjudication may not count as a "conviction"?